# Python Send to and figure out POST

Tags: python, post, get, chat

Recently, I've been attempting to figure out how I can find out what an unlabeled POST is, and send to it using Python.

The issue of the matter is I'm attempting to make a chat bot entirely in Python in order to increase my knowledge of the language.  For said bot, I'm attempting to use a chat-box that runs entirely on jQuery.  The issue with this is it has no knowledgeable POST or GET statements associated with the chat-box submissions.

How can I figure out what the POST and GET statements being sent when a message is submitted, and somehow use that to my advantage to send custom POST or GET statements for a chat-bot?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server in order to be able to receive any GET and POST requests, one of the easier ways to get that is to set up a Django project, ready in minutes and then add custom views to handle the request you want properly.

Comment: The issue is, I'm attempting to figure out POST requests sent via browser with JavaScript, and using those principles, send POST requests to emulate the action normally carried out by JavaScript.

Comment: @Rybo The network tab in the chrome developer tools will show that. I am sure `firebug` for firefox has an equivalent.